# Asserting entire response body in post man

Tags: json, postman, web-api-testing

I recently started working on spring boot projects.
I am looking for a way to assert the entire response of my API. 
The intention of this is to reduce the testing time taken for the API.

Found A few solutions mentioned below, but nothing helped me resolve the issue.

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("string_you_want_to_search");
});


pm.test("Body is correct", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.body("response_body_string");
});
```

When I put the entire response body as an argument, I get the below errors.

1. Unclosed String

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

Comment: Do you *need* to assert against a string? Your test is checking JSON but as a string, It doesn’t seem like a good approach. Why tag the question with JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same type of quotes you defined the string with inside it, you have to escape them:

- `'string with "quotes"'`
- `"string with 'quotes'"`
- `'string with \'quotes\''`
- `"string with \"quotes\""`

You probably want to put your json in single quotes as they are not allowed by json itself.

Comment: As *Postman* uses *JS* in *Tests/Pre-request Scripts*, you also can use a *grave accent*. Consider: `\`string with both 'single quotes' and "double quotes\``

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the response as a variable and then assert against that?

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.environment.set('responseData', JSON.stringify(jsonData))
```

From here you can get the data `JSON.parse(pm.enviroment.get('responseData'))` and then use this within any test to assert against *all* of the values.

```
pm.test("Body is correct", () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()
    pm.expect(jsonData).to.deep.equal(JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('responseData')))
})
```

My reasoning is that you’re trying to assert against JSON anyway but doing as a plain text string.

Or you could assert against the values separately like this:

```
pm.test("Body is correct", () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].employeeName).to.equal("tushar")
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].phNum).to.equal(10101010)
})
```

Depending on the JSON structure you may not need to access an array of data and the `[0]` can be dropped.